# How to fix 'Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 2002' error after fresh MAMP-installation?

Tags: mysql

My problem started with my XAMPP (on Windows 10). I couldn't access my phpMyAdmin anymore because the access was denied for some reason. I tried a bunch of different things and eventually re-installed XAMPP but that didn't fix the problem either, instead everything got worse. I tried to install MAMP as an alternative to XAMPP. When I first started MAMP, after the installation I could access the dashboard as well as phpMyAdmin - everything worked just fine. But as soon as I stopped the server and re-started him, the MySQL didn't work anymore. I re-installed MAMP several times now and it's always the same procedure. It works just after the installation but as soon as I restart the server it doesn't.

I've checked a lot of different threads on stackoverflow and other portals.

#### Other things I tried:

1. checked the server and mysql paramters in the `config.inc.php` file at `\MAMP\bin\phpMyAdmin`
2. deleted in `\MAMP\db\mysql` the logfiles `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` and restarted the server.
3. deleted in the same folder all files that are called `mysql-bin.` and restarted the server. I started the servers, the green light turned on (Apache and MySQL), the servers worked and I could access them. But as soon as I stopped the servers and re-started them, I've got the same problem `Debugging errno: 2002`, only the Apache worked but not the MySQL server.
4. switched the ports from `80` to `8888` for Apache and from `3306` to `8889` for MySQL via the MAMP settings. I've also tried port `3307`. Nothing was succesful.
5. turned off my firewall and anitivirus software temporarily
6. installed MAMP on different partitions (first I tried the standard directory C://MAMP/ for sure)

**I wrote a little bit of PHP code to check the connection:**

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

After the installation of MAMP I get this:

```
Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great. Host information: localhost via TCP/IP
```

After restarting the MAMP servers I get this:

```
Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 2002 Debugging error: Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte.
```

*Translation: Unable to connect because the target computer refused the connection.*

When I try to open phpMyAdmin I get this:
https://i.ibb.co/vxCxx5R/error-phpmyadmin.jpg
*(Cannot post the image directly due to missing reputations.)*

I have no clue what causes the problem but I have the gut feeling that is has either something to do with the ports or the MySQL service. Though, I can't find any port that is blocking the port 3306. I've tried to run the `mysql.exe` and `mysqld.exe` but nothing happens. I've also tried to run them as an administrator, even though I've got administartor rights already. The terminal pops up for less than a second and that's it, I can't find any service that is running.

Comment: I've installed the MySQL server, now the mysqld service is running but it's not connected to MAMP I think. In other works, if I start my servers then MAMP says MySQL must use Port `3306` but it's already used by mysqld. I can click _Use next free port_ which would be `3307` or _Setup new port_. If I click 'Use anyway' nothing happens. I'm not sure which of the solutions should help me with my problem. Also, I don't have the `etc` or `var` folders nor do I have the _socket file_ they are talking about.